# Merge multiple Arrays to one 2D Array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this code snippet here:

```
#define byte uint8_t

byte pins0[11] = {  0,  1,  2, 3,   4,  5,  6,  7, 63, 64, 65};
byte pins1[11] = {  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 60, 61, 62};
byte pins2[11] = { 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 15, 60, 61, 62};
byte pins3[11] = { 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 60, 61, 62};
byte pins4[11] = { 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 60, 61, 62};
byte pins5[11] = { 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 60, 61, 62};

byte *segPins[6] = {&pins0,&pins1,&pins2,&pins3,&pins4,&pins5};
```

The compiler shows an error:

```
src\main.cpp:15:63: error: cannot convert 'byte (*)[11] {aka unsigned char (*)[11]}' to 'byte* {aka unsigned char*}' in initialization
 byte *segPins[11] = {&pins0,&pins1,&pins2,&pins3,&pins4,&pins5};
                                                               ^
src\main.cpp:15:63: error: cannot convert 'byte (*)[11] {aka unsigned char (*)[11]}' to 'byte* {aka unsigned char*}' in initialization
src\main.cpp:15:63: error: cannot convert 'byte (*)[11] {aka unsigned char (*)[11]}' to 'byte* {aka unsigned char*}' in initialization
src\main.cpp:15:63: error: cannot convert 'byte (*)[11] {aka unsigned char (*)[11]}' to 'byte* {aka unsigned char*}' in initialization
src\main.cpp:15:63: error: cannot convert 'byte (*)[11] {aka unsigned char (*)[11]}' to 'byte* {aka unsigned char*}' in initialization
src\main.cpp:15:63: error: cannot convert 'byte (*)[11] {aka unsigned char (*)[11]}' to 'byte* {aka unsigned char*}' in initialization
*** [.pio\build\nanoatmega328\src\main.cpp.o] Error 1
```

In my opinion, `segPins` is an Array of `byte` pointers. So it should pass the compiler but it sees a difference?

Comment: shouldn't segPins be an array of ptrs to an array of 11 bytes?

Comment: `byte *segPins[11]` this way ?

Comment: `byte *segPins[6] = {pins0,pins1,...};`
&pins0 is a address of the pointer which is pointing on array of 11 elements and can be bind to `byte**ptr = &pins0`. PS: Note I'm talking now about the case when array decay to pointer but u should understand general situation)

Comment: No. `byte (*segPins[6])[11]`; However, brj's answer is simpler and more typically how this should be done.

Comment: Why using the pre-processor? use `type-alias` is safer. `using  byte = uint8_t;` or `typedef`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is

```
byte *segPins[6] = {pins0,pins1,pins2,pins3,pins4,pins5};
```

This is because `&pins0` refers to the address of the array `pins0`.

## Edit

For more information see answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c) question.